# MySQL/PHP storing multiple data points

Tags: php, mysql

I am relatively new to programming and databases.

I have a MySQL database with a "sales" table.  This table lists all sales in a state (i.e. each record is a particular sale), with fields for sellername, and buyerzip.  I would like to have another table "seller" that would include sellername, and also include fields to define the sellers market area by zip code - say 50+ zip codes define a market, and the seller could define multiple markets.

These market areas would be used for future queries: showing all sales in a particular market area.

Where do I start in terms of thinking how to store that "market area" data, and then use it for future queries?

Thanks

Comment: Picture a retail store - Store A might define its market as ZIp COdes 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 - and also define a separate market as 4,5,6,7,8,9,10.  Store B might define its market as 1,2,3,8,9,10,11,12.  I have data to show sales by all sellers to buyer in those zip codes - so I can show the market share of any given seller in any defined market.

Comment: Realistically - markets can be as small as a single zip code, or as large as several hundred zip codes - user can define their own market.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Table structure:

- Sales table: ID, sellerID, buyerZipcode, amount
- Seller table: ID, sellerName
- Market table: ID, marketName
- SellerMarketLink table: ID, sellerID, marketID
- MarketZipCode table: ID, marketID, zipCode

## Example data

Encoding the information in the first comment to your question

### Market table

1, "Store A, first market"
2, "Store A, second market"
3, "Store B market"

### MarketZipCode table

1, 1, 1
2, 1, 2
...
7, 1, 7
8, 1, 8
9, 2, 4
10, 2, 5
...
14, 2, 9
15, 2, 10
16, 3, 1
17, 3, 2
18, 3, 3
19, 3, 8
20, 3, 9
21, 3, 10
22, 3, 11
23, 3, 12

## Query

Total sales in a market for each seller. Note that since one zip code can be part of several markets, the total of all values in "Total Sales" can be larger than the sum of all 'amount' values in the Sales table.

```
select Market.marketName, Seller.sellerName, sum(Sales.amount) as "Total Sales"
from Sales join Seller join SellerMarketLink join Market join MarketZipCode
on (Sales.sellerID = Seller.ID AND Seller.ID = SellerMarketLink.sellerID 
  AND SellerMarketLink.marketID = Market.ID 
  AND Market.ID = MarketZipCode.marketID 
  AND MarketZipCode.zipCode = Sales.buyerZipCode)
group by Market.ID, Market.marketName, Seller.ID, Seller.sellerName
order by Market.marketName, Seller.sellerName
```

Comment: Thanks - I meant to circle back to this - this is what I was looking for - how to store the many-to-many relationship

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make the following assumptions here:

1. sellers have many markets
2. A market can span many zipcodes
3. Only one seller is responsible for a market
4. Markets can't overlap

Leading to the following structure...

sales table
seller | buyerzip

markets table
market | market_zipcodes_id

zipcodes table
market_id | zipcode

Hope that helps...

Comment: 1.  Sellers can have many markets  2. A market can have many zip codes  3.  multiple sellers can be in the market, thus markets can and do overlap.

Comment: That is left as an exercise to the reader. I've given you my assumptions upfront. If you want me to do this work for you, you'll have to pay me